# Android Studio gradle build got stuck

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[image]

Recently my android studio got stuck in gradle building very frequently, as shown in the picture above, which already took 30m to run and still keeps running. The only way to finish it is just force to stop android studio and restart the computer. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Your system configuration?

Comment: -Xms8192m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
@Abhimanyu